# Why does the text in td break before it reaches max-width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 70px;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc</td>
      <td>AB-AB-HELLO-WORLD-NINTENDO-MARIO-YOSHI-0042-LUIGI</td>
      <td>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</td>
      <td>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</td>
      <td>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why does the 'name' column wrap before the max-width is reached?
This won't happen if you use pure numbers or pure English.

How to make any text wrap again when it reaches max-width?

Comment: use `word-break: break-word;` (or `overflow-wrap: anywhere;`)

Comment: the `hyphen` provides a natural place for text to be wrapped - without that hyphen in the text in the `name` column you'd see a different result